# ICloud Sync has caused missing project files/folders

Tags: git, file, github, icloud

In an attempt to reduce the bird CPU %, I disabled the desktop & document folders iCloud Drive sync to my MacBook and wanted to keep a local copy. This was unsuccessful so upon syncing my Mac back to the iCloud Drive, I noticed that a lot of my github projects were missing files excluding package.json etc.

I can no longer find the files nor the changes I made to projects before the committing to github. How can I recover these lost files and successfully disable the iCloud Drive sync?

**EDIT**

The folders and files were found in a Archive Folder; hwoever, I am unable to place the projects and other folders into the documents folder.

Comment: Don't put Git repositories in any folder managed by a cloud syncing service, since that can cause corruption, as you've seen.

Comment: @bk2204 How can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: Put your repositories in a folder that isn't managed by iCloud.  Sync them using temporary commits and normal Git operations, or use rsync and SSH if the repository is completely idle (no Git processes at all running).